# nuxt buefy filter is not working in taginput field

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, buefy

I am using buefy taginput in my form, everything works as expect filter using ontype event.

only problem here is that i can see data in taginput box on when i focus, its getting selected too, but when i type its not getting filtered. for 10-15 items its not a problem but when its 1000+ items, it will be difficult. i don't know whats the problem here.

here is code so far.

```html
<template>
  <b-field label="Popular Destinations">
    <b-taginput
      v-model="form.popularSubDests"
      :data="allSubDests"
      autocomplete
      :allow-new="allowNew"
      :open-on-focus="openOnFocus"
      field="SubDestName"
      icon="label"
      placeholder="Add Cities"
      @typing="getFilteredSubdest"
    >
    </b-taginput>
  </b-field>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      openOnFocus: false,
      isSelectOnly: false,
      allowNew: false,
      allSubDestinations: [],
      form: {
        popularSubDests: [
          {
            SubDestName: null,
            SubDestId: null,
          },
        ],
      },
    }
  },

  computed: {
    allSubDests() {
      return this.allSubDestinations.map((item) => ({
        SubDestId: item.id,
        SubDestName: item.subdestname,
      }))
    },
  },

  methods: {
    getFilteredSubdest(text) {
      this.allSubDests = this.allSubDests.filter((option) => {
        return option.SubDestName.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(text.toLowerCase()) >= 0
      })
    },
  },

  async asyncdata({ route }) {
    let { data: allSubDest } = await axios.get(`process.env.FETCHSUBDEST`)
    return {
      allSubDestinations: allSubDest.results,
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: So, your thing is working well but not for 1000+ items? What is not working there? Also, a JS filter on 1000+ is probably not the best way to go.

Comment: no no, you understood wrong,, i meant, if there is 10 or 20 items then there should not be problem, i can use it by scrolling, but if there is 1000+ items, noone would want to scroll, overall the thing is, filter is not working on typing. not even for 10 items..

Comment: i followed buefy documentation, i can't see any help. i must be making some error here.

Comment: So, you have 2 issues: - making a working filter - find a way of display a lot of results with a good UI to your end users? For the first one, a [repro] could help debug the whole thing faster. For the second, you could limit the results (after filtering) to 10 or 20.